# What is the proper way to handle TLSNextProto in golang net/http?

Tags: http, ssl, https, go

Playing with golang's `net/http` package and SPDY. Something is really confusing me:

The `*tls.Conn` of  `TLSNextProto` function can't be read at all. Any read attempt will get a "connection reset by peer" error.

Run the following program, and then access `https://localhost:8080/` using Chrome with SPDY enabled.

Am I using the TLS connection object in a wrong way? Please help.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":8080",
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            NextProtos: []string{"spdy/3"},
        },
        TLSNextProto: map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler){
            "spdy/3": func(s *http.Server, conn *tls.Conn, h http.Handler) {
                buf := make([]byte, 1)
                if n, err := conn.Read(buf); err != nil {
                    log.Panicf("%v|%v\n", n, err)
                }
            },
        },
    }

    err := server.ListenAndServeTLS("/path/to/host.cert", "/path/to/host.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error or panic?

Comment: conn.Read() returns "connection reset by peer" error

Comment: Have you tried using the go.net/spdy library from https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/?repo=net#hg%2Fspdy ?

Comment: @Intermernet Thanks for you link. But it is frame encoding/decoding code only. None of Next Protocol Negotiation extension (NPN) included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I got it. It is the certificate issue. If the certificate used by server.ListenAndServeTLS() is not signed by a CA trusted by the browser(Chrome), connection will be reset. For creating you own CA and cert, following http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/